# `dotnet user-secrets` error "Could not load the MSBuild project" only for a specific user account

Tags: .net, sdk, account, dotnet-cli

### Details

- `dotnet user-secrets` `clear`, `list`, `remove`,  and `set`, all return "Could not load the MSBuild project" for a specific user account, but work fine with another user account and the Administrator.
- `dotnet user-secrets init` successfully adds a `UserSecretsId` property to the project file.
- The affected account is a local Windows account, lowercase with no spaces.

### Troubleshooting

- I uninstalled and reinstalled the .NET SDK from the Visual Studio installer.
- I tried troubleshooting permissions for the account for the following paths and sub-directories:

  - The project directory
  - `%AppData%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\`
  - `%ProgramFiles%\dotnet\`
  - `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\dotnet\`
  - `%UserProfile%\.dotnet\`

`dotnet --info`:

```
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.101
 Commit:    bb24aafa11

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19044
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\

Host:
  Version:      7.0.1
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       97203d38ba

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found
```

### Questions

- Is there a way I can track which files and directories are accessed by `dotnet user-secrets` so I can further troubleshoot a potential permissions issue?
- Is it possible to wipe any user settings or config data involving the .NET SDK and do a clean install?

Comment: Just in case... can you triple check you are running the clear/list/remove/set commands while your terminal is in the same directory as your .csproj file? Because uhh... I just wasted a lot of time because I was getting the same error as you and I was convinced I was in the correct directory, but wasn't ‍♂️